# Maven exec plugin question

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin, unzip

I'm using Maven 3.0.3 on Mac 10.6.6.  After packaging my war, I want to execute an unzip command (I want to do this because I'm using a Grails plugin that deletes the exploded war directory).  So I have this in my pom.xml …

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <executable>unzip</executable>
        <arguments>
            <argument>-d target/jx-1.0-SNAPSHOT target/jx-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

However, when I execute the command that invokes the plugin, I get the error …

```
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.1.1:exec (default-cli) @ jx ---
[INFO] UnZip 5.52 of 28 February 2005, by Info-ZIP.  Maintained by C. Spieler.  Send
[INFO] bug reports using http://www.info-zip.org/zip-bug.html; see README for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] Usage: unzip [-Z] [-opts[modifiers]] file[.zip] [list] [-x xlist] [-d exdir]
[INFO]   Default action is to extract files in list, except those in xlist, to exdir;
[INFO]   file[.zip] may be a wildcard.  -Z => ZipInfo mode ("unzip -Z" for usage).
[INFO] 
[INFO]   -p  extract files to pipe, no messages     -l  list files (short format)
[INFO]   -f  freshen existing files, create none    -t  test compressed archive data
[INFO]   -u  update files, create if necessary      -z  display archive comment
[INFO]   -x  exclude files that follow (in xlist)   -d  extract files into exdir
[INFO] 
[INFO] modifiers:                                   -q  quiet mode (-qq => quieter)
[INFO]   -n  never overwrite existing files         -a  auto-convert any text files
[INFO]   -o  overwrite files WITHOUT prompting      -aa treat ALL files as text
[INFO]   -j  junk paths (do not make directories)   -v  be verbose/print version info
[INFO]   -C  match filenames case-insensitively     -L  make (some) names lowercase
[INFO]   -X  restore UID/GID info                   -V  retain VMS version numbers
[INFO]   -K  keep setuid/setgid/tacky permissions   -M  pipe through "more" pager
[INFO] Examples (see unzip.txt for more info):
[INFO]   unzip data1 -x joe   => extract all files except joe from zipfile data1.zip
[INFO]   unzip -p foo | more  => send contents of foo.zip via pipe into program more
[INFO]   unzip -fo foo ReadMe => quietly replace existing ReadMe if archive file newer
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks, - Dave

Comment: Why not using the maven-dependency-plugin and using this instead of calling external programs (which make the build not portable!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're packing multiple arguments into one `<argument>`. That element takes exactly one argument, like "-d" or "target/jx-1.0-SNAPSHOT" from your example. You either have to break them up, or you can try using [`<commandlineArgs>`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#commandlineArgs) instead.

Answer (score 1):

As Ryan writes, you'll want this:

```
<argument>-d</argument>
<argument>target/jx-1.0-SNAPSHOT</argument>
<argument>target/jx-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war</argument>
```

But also, you are hard-coding lots of stuff that should be implemented using maven variables. So here's a better version:

```
<argument>-d</argument>
<argument>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</argument>
<argument>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</argument>
```